# SQL select from table with inner join on itself

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table (a view, actually)

```
id INTEGER, x1 INTEGER, y1 INTEGER, x2 INTEGER, y2 INTEGER
```

Now I need to select id of all lines, for which the sum of all values in that row with one given row is below zero,

> x1 + y1 + x2 + y2 + x3 + y3 + x4 + y4 < 0

Actually I have more complicated formulae, but it doesn't matter now. I understand that I must create INNER JOIN of this table with itself, but still can't compose the right expression.

I use SQLite + Python, if matters. It is about 100 000 rows in table and a valid result can be from all to none.

Comment: What do you mean with "one given row"?

Comment: I take one row from table and want to select all other rows whose sum with the chosen row is below zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you're after, than something like this should do it:

```
SELECT a.id
FROM mytable a
JOIN mytable b ON b.id=some_special_value
WHERE a.x1 + a.x2 + a.y1 + a.y1 + b.x1 + b.x2 + b.y1 + b.y2 < 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the next row.  Let me assume this is the smallest id greater than the id for a given row.  The following calculates the next id using a correlated subquery and then joins in the information for the next row:

```
select *
from (select t.*,
             (select t2.id from t t2 where t2.id > t.id order by t2.id limit 1
             ) nextId
      from t
     ) t left outer join
     t tnext
     on t.nextId = tnext.Id
where (t.x1 + t.y1 + t.x2 + t.y2) + (tnext.x1 + tnext.y1 + tnext.x2 + tnext.y2) < 0
```

You can then access the fields from `t` and `tnext`.

If you *know* that the next row has an `id` exactly 1 greater than its previous row, then you can simplify this to:

```
select *
from t left outer join
     t tnext
     on t.id + 1 = tnext.id
where (t.x1 + t.y1 + t.x2 + t.y2) + (tnext.x1 + tnext.y1 + tnext.x2 + tnext.y2) < 0
```

Comment: Sorry that I was not understood. The question is not about order of rows. Thanks for help attempt.